# Get Environment Variable with JOI

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables, joi

I'm using [joi](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.5.0#introduction) to structure data.
Now I'm unable to read environment variable set on startup.

I have a startup scrip.sh like:

```sh
PUBLIC_KEY="$(cat public_key.pem) docker-compose up --build"
```

Then I try to read that `PUBLIC_KEY` variable.

```js
const envVariables = joi.object({
 PUBLIC_KEY: joi.string()
    .default('PUBLIC_KEY')
})
```

I thought this would automatically identify the variable but it does not.
Is it possible to get the variable set on start up with Joi?

Answer (score 1):

You can get environment variables using the `process` core module. From the [documentation](https://nodejs.dev/learn/how-to-read-environment-variables-from-nodejs) :

> The process core module of Node.js provides the env property which
> hosts all the environment variables that were set at the moment the
> process was started.

For example,

```
const pubKey = process.env.PUBLIC_KEY
```

Comment: Am I initializing the `environment variable` correctly? Because I can't get it in any way I tried, even with your answer (it returns `undefined`).

Comment: No (sorry I missed that), I think what you want to do is to set `PUBLIC_KEY=$(cat public_key.pem)` from within your container where `node app.js` is run.

Answer (score 1):

1. Joi **does not** provide variables, at least in such a way you want
2. use it from the `process` if it's provided by CLI arguments or additionally use `dotenv.config()` to read synchronously from `.env` files
3. if you need to read some previous value inside Joi schema logic you e.g. for some conditions you cat try this example

```
var schema = {
    a: Joi.string(),
    b: Joi.string(),
    c: Joi.string().when('a', { is: 'avalue', then: Joi.string().required() }).concat(Joi.string().when('b', { is: 'bvalue', then: Joi.string().required() }))
};
```